# MeteorJS TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CHAR] [ERR_INVALID_CHAR]: Invalid character in header content ["Content-Disposition"]

Tags: meteor

We have a meteorJS app that keep crashing from time to time.
This is the error stack trace tracked:

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_CHAR] [ERR_INVALID_CHAR]: Invalid character in header content ["Content-Disposition"]
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:529:3)
    at packages/cfs_http-methods.js:622:17
    at Function._.each._.forEach (packages/underscore.js:147:22)
    at packages/cfs_http-methods.js:618:11
```

Any idea what's the cause?

EDIT: We do find this piece of code in server.js, that sets the header manually:

```
FS.HTTP.setHeadersForGet([
    ['Referrer-Policy', 'same-origin'], 
    ['Access-Control-Allow-Origin', Meteor.absoluteUrl()], 
    ['Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy', 'same-origin']
]);
```

I may also want to highlight that there was no major code changes recently and this legacy server has generally worked for years, until yesterday.

Comment: Is there any kind of load balancer or cache (like CloudFlare) in front of your meteor app server?

Comment: actually, wait this is a server side error, right? Can you show all the places in your code where you are setting response headers manually?

Comment: @christianFritz Yes the server uses cloudflare. For second question this will take sometime as it is a legacy server that we are maintaining. Let me try

Comment: @christianFritz found a piece of code that set header manually for all get request. included in original question